# How to call Lightbox rather than JS "alert"?

Tags: javascript, fonts, lightbox

I have a script that checks whether a specific font is installed or not in computer ([Code at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8afkT/)). If specified font is installed or not, in both conditions, js script calls the `alert()` function. How is it possible that if the font is "Installed" don't do anything but if the font is "Not Installed" just open light-box image viewer([This one](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/)) rather than `alert()` function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to use the lightbox plugin?

Comment: @Juhana No, I want to use light box alert as a `alert()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  this in your code. 
HTML add `anchor tag` can be hidden.

```
    <body>
    <a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/images/image-2.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption" style="display: none;" id="anchorId">image</a>
</body>
```

Use following script

```
//
// Call this function and pass in the name of the font you want to check for availability.
//
function doesFontExist(fontName) {
    // creating our in-memory Canvas element where the magic happens
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // the text whose final pixel size I want to measure
    var text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    // specifying the baseline font
    context.font = "72px monospace";

    // checking the size of the baseline text
    var baselineSize = context.measureText(text).width;

    // specifying the font whose existence we want to check
    context.font = "72px '" + fontName + "', monospace";

    // checking the size of the font we want to check
    var newSize = context.measureText(text).width;

    // removing the Canvas element we created
    delete canvas;

    //
    // If the size of the two text instances is the same, the font does not exist because it is being rendered
    // using the default sans-serif font
    //
    if (newSize == baselineSize) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if (!doesFontExist("Comic Sans MS"))
{
    alert('Comic Sans MS DOES NOT exist');
    $("#anchorId").click(); 
}
```

// You will need to add the js and css mentioned on the page [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/)

Here is working example from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWMB9/1/)
Remember It will show the image only if Font does not exist..

Comment: Yes that is exactly that what I want. Can I execute it in jsfiddle? Please create module. Thanks

Comment: Updated answer and given the jsfiddle working example. If this solves remember to accept answer

Comment: The image does not load in light box as mention on website. I mean how to use "overlay.png" image that have opacity of 80%.

Comment: See this. http://jsfiddle.net/GWMB9/3/ before asking please try basics as said on the site. we are not `lightbox support`

Comment: Thanks, now that is work fine. Sorry for newbie questions, actually I don't know coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have popup like [Light Box](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

So best way is to have one extra div and show/hide it with display property .

you can also use !Important for forcefully applying your display property. and give more z-index for that div when u show it .

```
enter code here

if (!doesFontExist("Comic Sans MS"))
{
    function('Comic Sans MS DOES NOT exist');
    // logic for displaying div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want pop-up like dialogue using not alert but html structure.

If you use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), you can use [Modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Or, You can generally follow another way.

1. Create Structure for showing containing `Font X`
2. Set object CSS `display: none;`
3. Add toggler (eg. `display: inline;` or `display: block;`) to trigger.

Comment: I am using this script on Wordpress.